# Python: Dictionary changed size during iteration"

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

The following python snippet results in a `"dictionary changed size during iteration"` error. But I do not modify the dictionary at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for key1 in d1:
    key2 = d1[key1]
    for keys in key2:
        values = d1[keys]
        if( key1 in values):
            print '\n\n', key1, keys, '\n'
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Nandita/Python/remove_duplicates.py", line 12, in <module>
        for key1 in d1:
    RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

EDIT:
d1 looks like this

1: 2, 4
2: 4, 7, 9
4: 1, 2, 5
6: 1, 7

Comment: Can you post more info about d1?

Comment: What the input data?  It works fine with `d1 = {'x':'y', 'y':'x','z':'y'}`.

Comment: It looks like there is more codes above there, are you sure you are not modfying it?

Comment: You're not using a `defaultdict` by any chance?

Comment: I am using a defaultdict, how does that affect things?